# How to delete pymongo.Database.Database object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo to connect to mongodb in my code. I am writing a google analytic kind of application. My db structure is like that for each new website I create a new db. So when someone registers a website I create a new db with that name, however when unregistering the website I wish the database to be deleted. I remove all the collection but still the database could not be removed

And as such the list of databases is growing very large. When I do

```
client = MongoClient(host=MONGO_HOST,port=27017,max_pool_size=200)
client.database_names()
```

I see a more than a 1000 list of apps. Many of them are just empty databases. Is there a way that I remove the mongo databases ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [drop_database](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html?highlight=drop_database#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.drop_database) method:

```
client = MongoClient(host=MONGO_HOST,port=27017,max_pool_size=200)
client.drop_database("database_name")
```